# Dynamic firebase.json file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It is quite difficult to keep track of the CSP rules in the `firebase.json` file, therefore I decided to add a script that constructs the proper rules. Now I need to manually update the firebase.json file every time I am changing something in the CSP configuration. Is there any way to dynamically configure firebase? I was hoping to achieve it with a simple renaming as it worked for many services grunt.json -> grunt.js I guess I can use some sort of templating but I wonder if there's a built-in mode to dynamically construct headers, rules etc for firebase.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a built-in way to generate `firebase.json` on command. I would recommend creating a script, e.g. `npm run deploy` that first generates your `firebase.json` content and then runs `firebase deploy`. That way you can make sure it's always regenerated before deployment.

```
// configureFirebase.js
const fs = require('fs');

const config = {
  hosting: {
    // ...
  }
}

fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/firebase.json', JSON.stringify(config));
```

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "node configureFirebase.js && firebase deploy"
  }
}
```